# Для чего нужен key в ListView.Items.Add()

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Один из перегруженных методов `listView1.Items.Add();` принимает такой параметр, как `string key`.

Что это за ключ и как им можно пользоваться в дальнейшем?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По этому ключу можно получать элемент коллекции.

```
var current = listView1.Items["Ваш ключ"];
```

В каких то случаях его удобнее использовать, чем индекс.

Comment: Т.е. этот ключ можно использовать только как параметр индексатора и никак иначе? А могу ли я  в каждом элементе коллекции в этом ключе хранить какую-нибудь уникальную информацию? И уже когда буду работать с i-ым элементом напрямую, при необходимости получать содержимое ключа i-ого элемента?

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин, не очень понял ваш вопрос, но вроде бы нет, да и зачем, если есть свойство `Tag` специально для этого предназначенное.